# Having trouble displaying data from SQL, it doesnt display

Tags: php, sql

I'm having trouble displaying the $row[product_name] it says blank while the $row2['index'] seems to be doing find all the data is being display, what seems to be the problem here? or it is illegal to put two parameters in while statement , any insights?

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_detail LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());


if($sql && $sql2){

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) && $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

 $product_name = $row["product_name"]; echo $row["product_name"] ;
 $product_id = $row2["product_id"];
 $product_qty = $row2["balance_qty"];
 $product_price = $row2["unit_price"];  


                    echo '  <tr>
                            <td>'.$product_id.'</td>
                            <td>'.$product_name.'</td>
                            <td>'.$product_price.'</td>
                            <td>'.$product_qty.'</td>
                           </tr><br/>';



    }
```

Comment: do a print_r($row) to see it's content. And no - you should do two fetch_array in the same while-loop.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Valid point, but you would still have the same problems iterating over the result, which is what seems to be causing trouble here.

Comment: You should read up about SQL joins. Unless you've got a very werid table structure, you could probably do that with a single query.

Answer (score 1):

Single Query with code something like this will get you back into the game:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, d.unit_price, d.balance_qty
FROM product AS p
JOIN product_detail AS d ON (d.product_id=p.product_id)
LIMIT 5";
$result =mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '  <tr>
    <td>'.$row['product_id'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['product_name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['unit_price'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['balance_qty'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an order of operations (precedence) issue here.  Try changing

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) && $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
```

to

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) && ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))){
```

Also, if you run out of records in `$sql` before you see all the records in `$sql2` the loop will not fetch the next `$row2`

Also, Is there a reason you can't do this with one query?

Answer (score 0):

what is the point of this:

```
$product_name = $row["product_name"];
```

just use the $row["product_name"] directly.

also do a check in this before going into the loop:

```
echo "FIRST: ".mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo "SECOND: ".mysql_num_rows($sql2);
```

they have the same number of rows? otherwise, you'll get into what @Umbrella says.